# How can I add english to SnowballStemmer inside NLTK?

Tags: nltk, snowball

I have installed all the possible packages from nltk.download() interface but still SnowballStemmer lacking about english language if I print all available. Ho can I add english to this stemmer in NLTK?

Comment: do you mind if you add the version of your NLTK before and after the update? that would be nice to document and let other people know about the issue when they encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just updated nltk with pip and problem is solved.